# How to safely disable segment reusing for one view?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these 3 registered routes (in this same order):

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{categoryName}/Page{pageNumber}", 
                new { action = "List" }, new { controller = "Products" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/Page{pageNumber}", 
                new { action = "List" }, new { controller = "Products" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{categoryName}", 
                new { action = "List" }, new { controller = "Products" });
```

The incoming url is: http://localhost:2575/Products/Housing/Page5.
Then, inside the view, I want to generate the outgoing Url:
http://localhost:2575/Products/Housing

My code for that is:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.CategoryName, "List",
                 new { categoryName = Model.CategoryName },
                 new { @class = "btn btn-info);
```

But instead the desired url (http://localhost:2575/Products/Housing) it generates:
http://localhost:2575/Products/Page5?categoryName=Housing

I've unit tested my route scheme and for this route data:

```
var routeData = new { controller = "Products", action = "List", categoryName = "Housing" };
```

It properly generates the expected url (http://localhost:2575/Products/Housing)

So, I think that somehow, the above Html helper, is taking the current route values and is trying to reuse them, that's the only explanation I can figure out for pageNumber having a value of 5 when I didn't specify it to the helper method.

Also, if in the view, before generating the URL I do:

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
ViewContext.RouteData.Values.Clear();
ViewContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", controller);
ViewContext.RouteData.Values.Add("action", action);
```

Then the URL is properly generated.
Note: Removing (or modifying) the value for the "categoryName" route value does not work, it keeps setting the pageNumber to the helper method.

If this is the case (segment reusing), how can I safely disable it? I'm afraid of having to clear the route data and then breaking something else. If not, what is going wrong here?